# php json multidimensional array syntax

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with the JSON I'm creating in PHP;  I create the array in a `while` loop from an sql query. `$featuresCSV` is a comma-separated string like `"1,3,4"`.  In the JSON I need it to end up like `feature-1: 1,feature-2: 1,feature-3: 1`  The `1` represents `true` for my checkbox in my front-end program.

```
while ($stmt2->fetch()) {

  $features = array();
  $featuresTmp = explode(',', $featuresCSV, -1);

  foreach ($featuresTmp as &$featureItem) {
    $features[] = array("feature-" . $featureItem => 1);
  }

  $items[] = array('price' => $price, 'image' => $image, 'features' => $features);
}
...
json_encode($output);
```

The JSON ends up looking like this:

```
{"price":8900,
"image":"4d3f22fe-9f1a-4a7e-a564-993c821b2279.jpg",
"features":[{"feature-1":1},{"feature-2":1}]}
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
{"price":8900,
"image":"4d3f22fe-9f1a-4a7e-a564-993c821b2279.jpg",
"features":[{"feature-1":1,"feature-2":1}]}
```

Notice how `feature-1` and `feature-2` aren't separated by brackets in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the elements at "feature-1" and "feature-2".

```
foreach ($featuresTmp as &$featureItem) {
   $features["feature-" . $featureItem] = 1;
}
```

The syntax `$feature[] = ...` is for appending to the end of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

```
while ($stmt2->fetch()) {

$features = array();
$featuresTmp = explode(',', $featuresCSV, -1);


foreach ($featuresTmp as &$featureItem) {
$features["feature-$featureItem"] = 1;
}

$items[] = array('price' => $price, 'image' => $image, 'features' => $features);
}
...
json_encode($output);
```